# проблема перевода строки в b.str версию

Tags: python

Мне нужно вывести строку вот так:

```
print(b."hello world")
```

Но что если у меня переменная вместо строки:

```
i="hello world"
print(b.i) - так не работает
```

Как мне правильно вывести?

Comment: что такое `b` и что такое `так не работает` ?

Comment: print(f"{b'i'}") Так сработает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = b'hello world'

print(i)
```

Без точки не работает.